# Case insensitive Postgres query with array contains

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have records which contain an array of tags like these:

```
   id   |                     title                     |       tags
--------+-----------------------------------------------+----------------------
 124009 | bridge photo                                  | {bridge,photo,Colors}
 124018 | Zoom 5                                        | {Recorder,zoom}
 123570 | Sint et                                       | {Reiciendis,praesentium}
 119479 | Architecto consectetur                        | {quia}
```

I'm using the following SQL query to fetch a specific record by tags ('bridge',  'photo', 'Colors'):

```
SELECT  "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE (tags @> ARRAY['bridge', 'photo', 'Colors']::varchar[]) ORDER BY "listings"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
```

And this returns a first record in this table.

The problem with this is that I have mixed type cases and I would like this to return the same result if I search for: `bridge`, `photo`, `colors`. Essentially I need to make this search case-insensitive but can't find a way to do so with Postgres.

This is the SQL query I've tried which is throwing errors:

```
SELECT  "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE (LOWER(tags) @> ARRAY['bridge', 'photo', 'colors']::varchar[]) ORDER BY "listings"."id" ASC LIMIT $1
```

This is the error:

> PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function lower(character varying[]) does not exist
>       HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can convert text array elements to lower case in the way like this:

```
select lower(tags::text)::text[]
from listings;

          lower           
--------------------------
 {bridge,photo,colors}
 {recorder,zoom}
 {reiciendis,praesentium}
 {quia}
(4 rows)
```

Use this in your query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM listings
WHERE lower(tags::text)::text[] @> ARRAY['bridge', 'photo', 'colors'] 
ORDER BY id ASC;

   id   |    title     |         tags          
--------+--------------+-----------------------
 124009 | bridge photo | {bridge,photo,Colors}
(1 row)
```

Comment: `lower(tags::text)::text[]` certainly works in all cases, but still it seems soo dirty

Comment: Dirty? It's a matter of taste. Dirty but fast! ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can't apply `LOWER()` to an array directly, but you can unpack the array, apply it to each element, and reassemble it when you're done:

```
... WHERE ARRAY(SELECT LOWER(UNNEST(tags))) @> ARRAY['bridge', 'photo', 'colors']
```

You could also install the [`citext` (case-insensitive text) module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/citext.html); if you declare `listings.tags` as type `citext[]`, your query should work as-is.

Comment: thank you Nick, accepted the other answer because it doesn't require installing additional extensions.